# ImportError: No module named json; python 2.6.6

Tags: python, json

I have installed Jmespath and it is internally using import json statement in lexer.py. I cannot change their source to import simplejson as json. HEnce, i wanted to know is there any work around to make this work?

```
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jmespath/lexer.py", line 3, in <module>
    from json import loads
```

Comment: Python 2.6 should already have the `json` module as part of the standard library - is your install corrupt?

Comment: I am not sure. Is there anyway i can check/verify it?

Comment: What operating system are you running? It looks like a Linux or Mac, but the commands will be different depending on what you're running.

Comment: I am running Linux RHEL 6 (2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64).

Comment: Strange that the stock Python on your OS would appear to be corrupt - are you missing the directory `/usr/lib/python2.6/json`? Does `python -c "import json"` fail on the command line? I don't have access to a RHEL6 install (or Centos6) but can you try using the command `yum reinstall python2.6`?

Comment: @Amith just open up an interactive python session and type `import json`. If it works, then you have a different problem.